# Not simple implies can fit into exact sequence?

Tags: abstract-algebra

If a group $G$ has a normal subgroup, call it $N$, then it can be fitted into a short exact sequence
$$1 \longrightarrow N \longrightarrow G \longrightarrow G/N \longrightarrow 1?$$

This sounds very general, is the reasoning correct?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes! It's true.

Comment: Oh excellent! That's the answer! Thank you so much Krish!